# How do you toggle status of functions of a function app in a slot?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-function-app

In Azure Functions (runtime version 2.x), I can use Azure CLI to toggle the state of a function (enable/disable) by using the command `az functionapp config appsettings set --name $functionAppName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --settings AzureWebJobs.functionName.Disabled=$disabled` but this only toggles the production slot. What is the correct syntax to toggle functions in the other slots? What should the `--name` parameter be? I tried `functionApp/stage` and `functionApp-stage` but get errors as if they don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use -s or --slot and specify the slot name.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp?view=azure-cli-latest#optional-parameters